# Bootstrap4 grid with angular2 layout issue

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I have implemented the bootstrap4 in the angular2 project and created the grid layout structure as follows.

**App.Component.html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <app-navigationbar></app-navigationbar>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <app-search></app-search>
        <app-product></app-product>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Navigation.Component.html**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-primary">
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

**Search.Component.html**

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="row line_height">
  <label>Product Title:</label>
</div>
<div class="row line_height">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Title">
</div>
<div class="row line_height">
  <label>Product Price:</label>
</div>
<div class="row line_height">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Price">
</div>
<div class="row line_height">
  <label>Product Category:</label>
</div>
<div class="row line_height">

  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Category">
</div>
<div class="row line_height">
  <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" class="btn-primary form-control" value="Search" />
</div>
</div>
```

**Product.Component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ngFor="let product of _products">
  <img src="./Content/Images/download.jpg" />
  <div>
    <label class="padding_left">First Product</label>
    <label class="padding_right">24.99</label>
  </div>
  <p>
    Test Description
  </p>
</div>
```

Got the following output

[image]
why is the search component not stacked in the right space of the container?

Please help me out this issue

Note: Used Bootstrap4 aplha6 css

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    **<div class="row">**
        <app-search></app-search>
        <app-product></app-product>
    **</div>**
</div>
```